# What is the definition of STI? (formely STD)

Tags: infection, terminology, sti

We know that for laymen, an STI (sexually transmitted infection) is something that can spread via sexual activities. However, there are some infections that can spread sexually but is not considered STI:s, like cholera. Also, there are a lot of STI:s that can be transmitted via non-sexual means. So it seems like STI means something that it *typically* spreads via sexual activities.

So my question is, is there any formal definition?

Comment: What did you look for? What did you find? Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @CareyGregory I have found dictionaries and mainstream medical papers, but nothing that I would quote as a descent source.